# Finding a sequence that has special properties

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, computer-science

let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Is is possible to find a sequence $S = \{ s_1, \dots, s_{n+k} \}$ ($k \leq n$) with a polynomial algorithm, so that for every pair $(x,y) \in S \times S$, the products $x \cdot y$ are pariwise distinct? Also $s_i \in S$ should be polynomial bounded with respect to $n$.

Regards,

Kreschew

Comment: Need at least a small change, because if $(x,y)\in S\times S$ then $(y,x)\in S\times S$. Maybe additional condition $x \le y$?

Comment: Why talk about s_{n+k} and not s_{n}? I fail to see the role of k here.

Comment: Umm yeah, thank you, forgot about that ;). Should be $x < y$. So you have $0.5(n-1)n$ possible choices for pairs...

Comment: Crossposted on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73167/sequence-with-a-special-property

Answer (score 1):

How about the prime numbers?  They are poly bounded and computable.

Added:  You can sieve up to $p$, giving about $p/\ln p$ primes in time $p \ln \ln p$, barely worse than linear.  But we can do better yet in the sense of reducing the highest number in the set.  Adding all numbers of the form $p^2,\ p^4,\ p^7,\ $ etc. will not spoil the fact that there are no matching products.  I'm sure we can do better yet.  If we know in advance how many we want, I think we can do better yet and will probably raise a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I how can you find $n+k$ Primes in polynomiell time?
'

Comment: Well, there is a polynomial time algorithm for determining whether a given number is prime. So you'd just search for the next prime after the previous term of your sequence. Bertrand's postulate guarantees that you won't have to search too long.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between $n$ and $k$.There are at least $n+k$ primes less than $(n+k)$^2, and you can check each number in polynomial time-see http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf.

Comment: The AKS primality algorithm is an overkill.  You can test whether an integer N is prime or not in time polynomial in N by trial division.  The point of the AKS algorithm is that its running time is polynomial in log N.

Comment: Yeah, of course, thanks. So how do you apply Betrands theorem to find n prime numbers that are polynomial bounded with repect to n. Bertrand theorem only says that there is at least one prime between $n$ and $2n$?

Comment: @Kreschew:  I don't think Bertrand's will get you $n$ polynomially bounded primes, but the prime number theorem will.  It says there are about $n/\log n$ primes below $n$.  I rounded up to say there are at least $n$ primes below $n^2$

Answer (score 1):

The unique factorization property of the integers ensures that if you choose your set to contain only primes it will have this property (subjected to Andre's correction).